# CQL Alias for Columns with Cassandra

Tags: jdbc, cassandra, cql

I'm using CQL Cassandra queries thanks to JDBC and i would like to use alias for columns.

For instance:

- select p1445 as age, p5423 as name from Table1

Do you know a workaround for handling this feature ?

Comment: don't think it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abhi is right, this is not yet supported.  It may be added for 2.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5075